# Best Practice for GCM in a multi-user context

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an application with a dedicated user registration and login system, where I'd like to integrate GCM for downstream messaging.

My question would be now what the best practice/approach would be to do so. I could either

1. use one single GCM token across all user sessions
2. or request a new GCM token upon a login and try to unregister it upon the logout ("try to" because there might be no network connection)

I could imagine pros and cons for both approaches but lack the in-depth GCM experience to say which one would be better.

Anything else I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to keep a single GCM token for multiple users. When you send the push notification send a custom node as username or userid to which you want to send the notification.

When you actually receive the notification check for the currently logged-in user and if it matches with the node passed in push notification then show the notification to the user and if it doesn't discard it (or store it locally to be displayed when that user logs in).

In practical scenario one phone will be used by only one user (with very few exceptions may be), so you shouldn't worry about saving it either. But that could be a business decision.

**Update**

Google very clearly says that after un-registering and again registering for GCM token may be same. So there is no point in un-registering and registering for GCM again and again. Here is the snippet of official document.

> A registration token isn't associated with a particular logged in user. If the client app unregisters and then re-registers, the app can receive the same registration token or a different registration token.

[Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration)

Comment: What would you consider the downside of the second approach (apart from more complexity)? Multi-user Android setups are actually something I havent even taken into account yet.

Comment: There is no use of keep on un-registering and registering for GCM. I don't see any advantage in second approach that's why I said I would prefer first approach.

Comment: The idea of re-registering came from the assumption that a new registration returns a new ID, which would be freshly associated with the new user. As I now found out there is a possibility that the same token will be returned. Is that what you meant? In that case a re-registration would really not make much sense.

Comment: Yes it is possible that same token will be returned.